# How to find all Doorkeeper applications that have been authorized by the resource owner

Tags: doorkeeper

I am baffled by the fact that `Doorkeeper` does not provide a utility method to get a list of `Doorkeeper::Application` that the resource owner has authorized. This information is needed for the very common use case of providing the user with a list of authorized applications that they can revoke consent for.

The method to revoke all access tokens for a specific application is:

```rb
Doorkeeper::AccessToken.revoke_all_for(application_id, resource_owner)
```

To get the application ids of currently authorized applications I have to do this:

```rb
application_ids = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.by_resource_owner(resource_owner).where(revoked_at: nil).pluck(:application_id).uniq
```

but am not sure this is enough since Doorkeeper [allows the `revoked_at` to be set in the future](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/c48fd2d989e761ab3ebe21698fcfa70261df7f57/CHANGELOG.md?plain=1#L775C16-L775C16) and the above query might miss some applications.